# Singletone method

Tags: java, methods, singleton

I need a method that will always be executed in one instance. For example, this method was called from different class instances and different threads at the same time. In this case, they should be executed one at a time, and not simultaneously, despite the fact that they are called from different instances.
I cant make it just static and synchronized, because it have a lot of inner code, which cant be refactored to static
For now I have next idea:

```
private static Boolean isMethodRun = false;

public void singletoneMethod() {
        synchronized(Boolean) {
            if (!isMethodRun) {
            isMethodRun = true;
            } else {
                for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                    if (isMethodRun) {
                        Thread.sleep(2_000);
                    } else {
                        isMethodRun = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        try {
            //inner code
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            //logs
            throw e;
        } finally {
            isMethodRun = false;
        }
    }
```

Is there any prettier way to get such functionality

Comment: This code is not safe. If one thread reaches 5th line without executing and second thread also reaches 5th line, then access to try block is given for 2 thread at same time.
Why you cant use synchronized block on 5th line?

Comment: @mateuszl1995 thanks, you are right. I will edit it right now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way would be to synchronize the method. Since you appear to have defined the `isMethodRun` variable static, it looks like you would want to synchronize on a static thing:

```
private static final Object lock = new Object();

public void singletoneMethod() {
  synchronized (lock) {
    // The code you want only to execute one-at-a-time.
  }
}
```

You could have synchronized on the class - `synchronized (WhateverYourClass.class)` - but that is vulnerable to anybody in the JVM synchronizing on the class elsewhere. Using an inaccessible `Object` like this is more robust.

Comment: I have mentioned next: " I cant make it just static and synchronized, because it have a lot of inner code, which cant be refactored to static"
It means I cant just synhronyze all inner resources, because its inner methods sometimes. Im trying to use my boolean flag-variable just to give all methods know, is there their copy which is run an current moment

Comment: @Keker This doesn't require that your inner code be made static..

Comment: @Keker a synchronized block is only mutually synchronized with respect to other synchronized blocks using the same monitor (`lock`, in this case). It doesn't "lock everything everywhere": all you're ensuring here is that only one thread is inside that block at a time. And nothing has changed about the static-ness.

Comment: hmm, Is synchronized block makes everything  inside thread safe? or will only those operations be thread safe that use the resource specified in parentheses?

Comment: @Keker from the point of view of what you're asking, a synchronized block with a static final monitor just stops more than one thread entering the block at once. (The other part of it is that all actions executed in the block on one execution [happen before](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/memconsist.html) the start of the execution of the next block. This doesn't mean it's inherently *thread-safe*, but may be necessary for it).

Comment: Thank you for help and detailed explanation

Answer (score 1):

So basically you want only one `singletonMethod` call to proceed at a time<sup>1</sup>.

This is the simplest solution:

```
public static synchronized void singletonMethod() {
    // your business logic here 
}
```

You said:

> I can't make it just static and synchronized, because it have a lot of inner code, which can't be refactored to static

I'm not convinced that it *can't* be refactored<sup>2</sup>, but if you say so, here are some alternatives:

```
private static final Object lock = new Object();  // Must be static!

public void singletonMethod() {
    synchronized (lock) {
        // your business logic here
    }
}
```

Or

```
public static synchronized void oneAtATime(Runnable runnable) {
     runnable.run(); 
}
```

You could use the `oneAtATime` method like this:

```
oneAtATime(() -> { // your business logic here });  // Java 8+

oneAtATime(new Runnable() {
               public void run() {
                   // your business logic here
               }
});
```

Apart from the first one (at the top), these alternatives all allow you to refer to instance variables in the "business logic".  You just need to implement the "business logic" in the appropriate scope.  (And even in the first case, it is trivial to pass an instance reference to a static method so that it can call methods on the instance.)

To use the above in a thread-safe fashion, you need to ensure that the "business logic" is all thread-safe.  That will depend on other code in the application; e.g. how other threads / methods use any shared objects that this "business logic" is operating on.

---

> why would static be needed here? Can't it just be public synchronized void singletonMethod? Or do the memory barriers not work for accessing static fields? – luk2302 25 mins ago

We need a `static` lock or a `static synchronized` method in order to meet the stated requirement that only one call is in progress at a time.  If there is more than one lock, you won't get serialization.

It would be possible to implement the "one at a time" logic as a `synchronized` instance method of a (properly implemented) Singleton class.  However, there is not much point unless you have other good uses for the Singleton class.  (Bear in mind that the Singleton pattern brings problems of its own.)

---

<sup>1 - This is not what the term "singleton" conventionally means ...

2 - In fact the refactoring required is trivial.  Just put your business logic into an instance method of `YourClass` declared as (say) `businessLogic()`.  Then you can define the one-at-a-time method in `YourClass` as follows: `static synchronized void singleton(YourClass arg) { arg.businessLogic(); }`.  You would typically use it (within `YourClass`) like this: `YourClass.singleton(this);`</sup>